# Rounding a float to the nearest value in a pre-determined list?

Tags: objective-c, numbers, rounding, nearest-neighbor

I have a set list of valid sizes for a UI object on my display (values at which a background image tiles the way I want it to), and I want to take each object's height in turn and round it up to the next highest value in that set list. For instance, if the list contained `49`, `83`, `114`, `148`, and `179`, and if I passed in `1` I'd get `49`, if I passed in `30` I'd get `49`, if I passed in `50` I'd get `83`, etc. Obviously I'm going to write a separate method to return one of the valid sizes and call it on each object in turn.

I'm a fairly new programmer and am trying to work out an efficient way to do it. My idea was to run a `while` loop, adding one to the value until it equals one of the set values, then return that set value. This should work since there are no decimals involved, but I'm doubting whether it's t he safest way. Is there a more efficient approach than looping? I'm using Objective-C for the iPhone if anyone wants to offer example code or objects I can use.

Comment: A binary search would be better if your list was long, but the accepted answer is good for a short list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop is the right way, but loop over the array of values until you find the one that fits.  This way you only go through the loop a maximum of 5 times if there are 5 valid sizes.  I wrote a short example using NSInteger as the type:

```
- (NSInteger)findValidSize:(NSInteger)aSize
{
    // create a NSArray containing NSNumber objects
    NSArray* validSizes = @[ @49, @83, @114, @148, @179 ];

    for (NSNumber* validSize in validSizes) {
        if (aSize <= [validSize integerValue]) {
            return [validSize integerValue];     // found it
        }
    }

    // nothing valid was found, now what? return the last valid size?
    return [[validSizes lastObject] integerValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
-(NSInteger)nearestNumberTo:(NSInteger)number{
    NSArray *array=@[@(49), @(83), @(114), @(148), @(179)];
    NSInteger nearest=[array[0]integerValue];
    /*
    for (NSInteger index=0; index<array.count; index++) {
        if ([array[index]integerValue]>=number){
            nearest=[array[index]integerValue];
            break;
        }
    }
    */
    for (NSNumber *num in array) {
        if ([num integerValue]>=number){
            nearest=[num integerValue];
            break;
        }
    }
    return nearest;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    //49, 83, 114, 148, and 179
    NSInteger minimum=[self nearestNumberTo:86];
    NSLog(@"%ld",minimum);

}
```